# Saving a captured image using OV7670 camera and Raspberry Pi Pico error

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I am trying to save the captured images for OV7670 camera module using Raspberry pi pico.I have written a code in CircuitPython to save the image in bmp format.But when i try to download the image from pico and view, i am getting a pixelated image.I am beginner to pico and CircuitPython.So please guide me where my code is wrong and what to be changed.

I have tried using this code

CODE:

```
        import time
        import storage
        from displayio import (
            Bitmap,
            Group,
            TileGrid,
            FourWire,
            release_displays,
            ColorConverter,
            Colorspace,
        )
        import displayio
        from adafruit_st7789 import ST7789
        from adafruit_bitmapsaver import save_pixels
        import board
        import busio
        import digitalio
        from adafruit_ov7670 import (
            OV7670,
            OV7670_SIZE_DIV1,
            OV7670_SIZE_DIV16,
        )

        # Set up the display (You must customize this block for your display!)
        release_displays()
        spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.GP2, MOSI=board.GP3)
        display_bus = FourWire(spi, command=board.GP0, chip_select=board.GP1, reset=None)
        display = ST7789(display_bus, width=320, height=240, rotation=270)


        # Ensure the camera is shut down, so that it releases the SDA/SCL lines,

        # then create the configuration I2C bus
        with digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP10) as reset:
            reset.switch_to_output(False)
            time.sleep(0.001)
            bus = busio.I2C(board.GP9, board.GP8)

        # Set up the camera (you must customize this for your board!)
        cam = OV7670(
            bus,
            data_pins=[
                board.GP12,
                board.GP13,
                board.GP14,
                board.GP15,
                board.GP16,
                board.GP17,
                board.GP18,
                board.GP19,
            ],  # [16]     [org] etc
            clock=board.GP11,  # [15]     [blk]
            vsync=board.GP7,  # [10]     [brn]
            href=board.GP21,  # [27/o14] [red]
            mclk=board.GP20,  # [16/o15]
            shutdown=None,
            reset=board.GP10,
        )  # [14]

        width = 320
        height = 240

        bitmap = displayio.Bitmap(cam.width, cam.height, 65535)
        g = Group(scale=1, x=(width - bitmap.width) // 2, y=(height - bitmap.height) // 2)
        tg = TileGrid(
            bitmap, pixel_shader=ColorConverter(input_colorspace=Colorspace.RGB565_SWAPPED)
        )
        g.append(tg)

        # BMP header
        bmp_header = bytearray(54) #The size of the bmp header file (max size)
        bmp_header[0:2] = b"BM"  # first 2 bytes Signature of the BMP file
        bmp_header[2:6] = (cam.width * cam.height * 2 + 54).to_bytes(4, "little")  # next 4 bytes is File size
        bmp_header[10:14] = (54).to_bytes(4, "little")  # Offset indicates the offset from start of the file to begining of the data
        bmp_header[14:18] = (40).to_bytes(4, "little")  # Info header size
        bmp_header[18:22] = cam.width.to_bytes(4, "little")  # Image width
        bmp_header[22:26] = cam.height.to_bytes(4, "little")  # Image height
        bmp_header[26:28] = (8).to_bytes(4, "little")  # Planes
        bmp_header[28:30] = (16).to_bytes(2, "little")  # Bits per pixel

        t0 = time.monotonic_ns()
        #display.auto_refresh = False
        count = 0
        while True:
            count = count + 1
            cam.capture(bitmap)
            bitmap.dirty()
            #display.refresh(minimum_frames_per_second=0)
            t1 = time.monotonic_ns()
            print("fps", 1e9 / (t1 - t0))
            t0 = t1
            bim = bytearray(bitmap)
            image_size = len(bim) * 2  # Multiply by 2 bytes per pixel
            file_size = 54 + image_size
            bmp_header[2:6] = (file_size).to_bytes(4, 'little')
            
            # Save the image as a BMP file
            bmp_data = bmp_header + bim
            with open('efpsl.bmp', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(bmp_data)
            if count == 3:
                break
```

Image:

[Screenshot of the saved image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhRJI.png)